Selenium accordion element to be clickable
I have the following HTML code:
<spaui-accordion _ngcontent-ouh-c26="">
                    <spaui-accordion-tab _ngcontent-ouh-c26="" id="accordioAcordosPendentes" successtext="Carregando Acordos..." _nghost-ouh-c35="" class="ng-tns-c35-3 ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="row"></div>
<div _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="accordion-tab" data-spaui-accordion-tab-header="Acordos (6)">
    <!----><div _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="ng-tns-c35-3 ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="accordion-tab-heading">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <h4 _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="accordion-tab-title">
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!----><span _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="ng-tns-c35-3 label-margin ng-star-inserted" style="max-height: 50px;">
                    <!---->
                    <!----><div _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="animated-box ng-tns-c35-3 ng-star-inserted">
                        <p _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="ng-tns-c35-3" id="animatedText">Acordos (6)</p>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <!---->
                <span _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="accordion-tab-button" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <!----><em _ngcontent-ouh-c35="" class="ng-tns-c35-3 ng-star-inserted icon-seta-baixo"></em>
                    <!---->
                </span>
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                

                
                <!---->
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---->

    <!---->

    <!---->

    <!---->
</div>
</spaui-accordion-tab>
                </spaui-accordion>

This code is shown after i've realyzed a few clicks \ steps on the page i'm trying to access with Selenium.
I'm having difficulties to wait for the accordion "accordioAcordosPendentes". It takes a few seconds to load, however, i've tried all wait conditions available and couldn't get it to wait until its available ; always throwing an exception that the element isn't clickable.
However, if i'm debugging the code and just wait a few seconds...it will work. But even if i try Thread.Sleep on my code and leave it running, there are situations where it will just throw the exception
Here is what i've tried so far:
                //var aguardaLinkAcordo = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((By.LinkText(tipoAcordo))));
                // aguardaLinkAcordo.Click();
                
                var linkAcordo = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(tipoAcordo));
                linkAcordo.Click();
                
                new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((By.CssSelector("#accordioAcordosPendentes > div.accordion-tab > div > div > h4 > span.accordion-tab-button")))).Click();
                
                
                
               // var disponivel = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#accordioAcordosPendentes > div.accordion-tab > div > div > h4 > span.accordion-tab-button > em"));
               // disponivel.Click();
                //var aguardaAccordion = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.CssSelector("#accordioAcordosPendentes > div.accordion-tab > div > div > h4 > span.accordion-tab-button > em"))));
                // aguardaAccordion.Click(); //If the accordion is available for clicking (expanding), click on it to expand                
                //var availableX = Retry.Do(() => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#accordioAcordosPendentes > div.accordion-tab > div > div > h4 > span.accordion-tab-button > em"))TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),4);

//               available.Click();

Of course, commented lines are what i've tried also but no success. I tried an method to ignore the exception and keep retrying, but no luck also:
public static IWebElement TryThreeTimes(IWebElement element)
{
    var tries = 10;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            element.Click();
            break; // success!
        }
        catch
        {
            if (--tries == 0)
                throw;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    return element;
}

Any input is appreciated. Thanks a lot and sorry for the english.
